# How to stop and restart animation in UIView block animation

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios6

I have checked and tried variety of answers . But still it didn't work for me.
Here is my code,

```
-(void)animate {

    [img1 startAnimating];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:10
                     animations:^{

                         img1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -1000);}];

    [img2 startAnimating];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:13
                     animations:^{
                         img2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -1000);}];

}
```

I want to get animation started when i press one button and stop when i press another. It works fine for start and stop . but problem comes when i restart it by pressing on start button which calls this method again. Nothing happens when i call second time ??????

Answer (score 4):

[Transformation unable to perform twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344617/transformation-unable-to-perform-twice/12345535#12345535)

Hi you need to use the completion block to perform this animation,

Initialize like this some where else....

```
@interface YourClass()

{
    CGAffineTransform trans1 ;

    CGAffineTransform trans2 ;

}

@End
....


    -(void)animate {


        [_img1 startAnimating];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:10
                         animations:^{
                             trans1 = _img1.transform; //  
                             _img1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -1000);} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                 _img1.transform = trans1;
                             }];

        [_img2 startAnimating];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:13
                         animations:^{
                             trans2 = _img2.transform; 
                             _img2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -1000);} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                 _img2.transform = trans2;
                             }];

    }
```

Comment: Would you please explain it ?? I didn't get you

Comment: Alert ? what alert can elaborate pls

Comment: Yes i did. Issue comes at >> trans1 = _img1.transform;   . It tells "Variable is not assignable"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39974/discussion-between-karan-alangat-and-spynet)